# how to find out what Theme or extension

Tags: database, theme, url, module

I have a magento site and would like a feature like this, where a customer can build there own unique piece of furniture.
the site below has something i thing would work

http://www.buildabasket.com/build

However since i am not a programmer, I was wondering if anyone knew how i could get the theme or extension information to continue my research as far as cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to know which extension or theme the site is using.

But you can accomplish this by creating Bundle Products, but by default, it isn't going to look like the page you mentioned. You'll have to (or hire someone to) custom create a page (extension) like that.

With bundle products, you can specify a set of options, and add simple products to each option.

For more info about bundle products, check the [Magento documentation](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/product-bundle.html%3FTocPath%3DProduct%2520Catalog%7CCreating%2520Products%7C_____6)